# Android: Interface vs get method

Tags: java, android, interface, fragment

In each default fragment there is an interface, like this:

```
public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener
{
    void onFragmentInteraction(String string);
}
```

which is called in this way:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context)
{
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener)
    {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction("Interfaccia fragment");
    } else
    {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}
```

It is useful to send data to the activity with the implementation of the method of the interface:

```
@Override
public void onFragmentInteraction(String string)
{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), string,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Also I can do the same with a get method in the fragment

```
public String get()
{
    return "Interfaccia fragment";
}
```

which is called by the activity in this way:

```
BlankFragment blankFragment = BlankFragment.newInstance("","");  
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),blankFragment.get(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

So, if there are few values (only one value too), how can I do? With the first or the second method? I think that the second is faster, but the first is more complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to maintain a reference to the fragments in the activity, because they could be destroyed and recreated.  So go with the interface, and not the get method.